# Perl finding file size

Tags: perl

Please find my code snippet

```
my $filename = "/var/nxt/projs/apr/interfaces/output/ELA/$final_file";

print "File name is \n";
print $filename;
my $filesize =  (stat($filename))[7];
print "pradip output\n ";
print "%s",$filesize;
```

but the value of filesize is not getting printed

can someone please help???

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`printf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html), not `print()`,

```
printf("%s",$filesize);
```

Also you might want to check if `stat` actually found your file/file size,

```
my $filesize =  (stat($filename))[7] // die "no filesize!\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `-s` option

`my $filesize =  -s $filename;`

Answer (score 0):

See the below code if it is helpful:(For $filename - Give complete path of the file)

```
my $filename = "c:/Users/user001/Desktop/file.txt";
print "File name is \n";
print $filename . "\n";
print "File size is \n";
print -s $filename;
```